# Microsoft Access DB - Where field not equal

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2010

I have this query:

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.UserEmail 
FROM Users 
WHERE Users.FirstName LIKE '%1%' OR 
      Users.LastName  LIKE '%1%' OR 
      Users.UserEmail LIKE '%a%' AND 
      Users.UserEmail <> 'a@a.a';
```

Where the content in the LIKE is 'a' I don't get the email 'a@a.a' as a result, but if for example the first name or the last name that related to this email contains the char 1, I get this email in the result.

My question is why and how can prevent it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your "or"s with parenthesis.

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.UserEmail 
FROM Users 
WHERE
(
   Users.FirstName LIKE '%1%' OR 
      Users.LastName  LIKE '%1%' OR 
      Users.UserEmail LIKE '%a%'
)
 AND 
      Users.UserEmail <> 'a@a.a';
```

Reason is because as soon as the first "or" condition was satisfied, then the "not" part doesn't matter since it wasn't separated with the parenthesis.